# how to call upon a list in my code using OOP?

Tags: python, oop, big-o

I want my code to be able to make a list and measure how long it takes for the code to run relative to the input size and the size of the list

```
import time
def minmax(sequence):
    userlist=[]

    while True:
        
        usernum = input("Input a number, ")
        print("Your current input is: ", usernum)
        
        if usernum != '0': 
            userlist.append(usernum)
           
        else:
            print(userlist)
            print('(',min(userlist),',',max(userlist),')')
            sequence =[ i for  i in range(userlist)]
            start=time.time()
            print(userlist,time.time-start)
            break
```

Comment: You didn't call `time.time` a second time: `time.time() - start`. But, that gets evaluated *before* `print` gets called, so you aren't actually timing anything.

Comment: Do you want the big-o or actual time (ex. in seconds)?

Comment: I want the big o

Comment: i copied and pasted the code.  it does not work because of the indentation.  please fix this.

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with the indentation so I can fix it, please?